pmplots Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L)/Error in deprecated()
I was using the packages pmplots and came across this error message. I can reproduce the error using its example on the website.(https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/pmplots/blob/main/inst/examples/pmplots_complete.Rmd)
```{r}
library(pmplots)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
Sys.setenv(LANG="en")
```

\newpage

## Example data in the package
```{r global}
df <- pmplots_data_obs() %>% mutate(CWRES = CWRESI)

id <- pmplots_data_id()

dayx <- defx(breaks = seq(0,168,24))

.yname <- "MRG1557 (ng/mL)"

etas <- c("ETA1//ETA-CL", "ETA2//ETA-V2", "ETA3//ETA-KA")

covs <- c("WT//Weight (kg)", "ALB//Albumin (g/dL)", "SCR//Creatinine (mg/dL)")

```
### Fill in `CWRES` if it doesn't exist
```{r, message = TRUE}
dat <- mutate(df, CWRES = NULL)

cwresi_time(df)

cwres_time(dat)
```

Error in deprecated() : could not find function "deprecated" 
*I dont know which packages it relies on as deprecated() appears in multiple packages??

```{r}
dv_pred(df, yname = .yname)
```

Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments

It doesn't work in dv_pred(), but works fine if using ggplot, as dv_pred() is fully packed it is hard for me to identify how to fix the error message?
do you have any suggestions???
